# Animate background of single datagrid cell on binding source updated

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I would like to changed the background of a singe cell in a datagrid when the source is updated. I am using MVVM, C# and WPF:

Here is my not working code form the xaml file (only the datacell itself):

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="test" Header="Errors" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding ErrorsReceived}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.SourceUpdated">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="test"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                            From="Red"
                                            To="White"
                                            Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't had a chance to run it yet but you've tried to set a style without a style being defined and you're trying to animate a color with a double animation, try something like this.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Errors" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding ErrorsReceived}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                 <Style>
                     <Style.Triggers>
                         <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.SourceUpdated">
                              <BeginStoryboard>
                                  <Storyboard>
                                      <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" From="Red" To="White" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                   </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                     </EventTrigger>
                       </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>
           </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
     </DataGridTextColumn >
```