# Animate DataGrid cell background on TargetUpdated event

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

I've been searching all over for a solution, but found nothing that works.

The problem is simple:

- DataGrid (read-only) is bound to a collection of objects (implementing INotifyPropertyChanged)
- When certain properties of data objects change, the cell background should animate (eg. from Red to Transparent)

I've tried using styles with EventTrigger (TargetUpdated) to start a Storyboard, but it has side-effects, all cells' background is animated when DataGrid is first populated, and also when it is scrolled or re-sorted.

I know there are few other similar questions, but I didn't see a working solution.
Has anyone been able to achieve this? I'd very much prefer not to have any code-behind, but if it's necessary, I'll live with it...

EDIT:
I've noticed there is some confusion as to what I'm trying to achieve:
Let's say a cell (and it's underlying property on data object) has a value "A". At some point it changes to "B" (e.g. update from a server). At this point the background should 'flash' (e.g. 1 second animation from Red to Transparent). At all other times the background should be Transparent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been finally pointed in right direction on MS forum, the solution is to use attached behavior that registers OnTargetUpdated handler and starts s Storyboard. I've tried this approach earlier, but apparently one must start the Storyboard only if IsLoaded property of the cell is true. That gets rid of side effects I mentioned above.

Here is the link to the [forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/81bb60bc-ade3-4f5e-b39f-e0a5451ffee8).

Comment: thank you for posting the solution for other Marin, this gave a clear idea for me too. I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

add a converter something like this :

```
namespace System.Converters
{
//Converter for cell animation 
  public  class flashConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string cellvalue = value.ToString();
        return cellvalue = ("place the condition here");
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}
in your MainWindow.xaml.cs add the namespace

```
   xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:YourProjectName.Converters"
```

in your resources add the following :

```
          <DataGrid.Resources>
          <loc:flashConverter x:Key="SomeConverter"></loc:flashConverter>
         </DataGrid.Resources>
```

In your DatagridTextColumn add the following :

```
  <DataGridTextColumn Header="yourDatagridHeader"  IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=yourDatagridHeader}">
             <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <!--Style to implement the datagrid cell animation for yourDatagridcell-->
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
             <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding yourDatagridHeader}" Value="Give your condition here">
            <!-#E6F85050 is the hexadecimal value for RED-->
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E6F85050"/>
             </DataTrigger>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding yourDatagridHeader}" Value="Give your condition here">
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="give the hexadecimal value for transparent here "/>
              </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
      </DataGridTextColumn>
```

hope this helps !

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how this can work. You are declaring a Converter flashConverter but it's not used anywhere... I can only guess you meant the converter should return "Running" or "Stopped" values, but the problem is when to switch from Running to Stopped; this would require some kind of timer...

Comment: I have edited now.. Please look that I have added 
"namespace HMSystem.Converters"
before my flashconverter {} and I have added this namespace in my XAML code.. inside the <Window />. first try to write the converter class, save it and then add it to the namespace, so the Intellisense can know it.
and for the "Running" and "Stopped" are just examples, you should give your condition there to trigger it.

Comment: You are still not using the converter anywhere... Have you actually tried this code? In any case, the converter will NOT be called unless there is a change in the source object, so the value "Stopped" will never be returned. I hope you understand my original question, which states the backgorund should *animate* on data CHANGE, not on value of the data.

Comment: Actually I have not tried yet. I just gave an idea.. but what you have said is actually true.. pls try to post on [Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/threads) so that you can find help on that forum too

Comment: Not in any way compatible with MVVM paradigm... Only solution I'm able to come up with is using timers in data model to reset a property that signals that another property has changed. I don't like this approach one bit, but can't figure out another way.

Comment: Try this solution proposed on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253963/animate-background-of-single-datagrid-cell-on-binding-source-updated).. Its not accepted though

Comment: That solution won't work, first it uses SourceUpdated event (so it will trigger only when user changes data in the grid), and second, even if TargetUpdated is used, the cells would blink on scrolling and sorting the grid (tried it).

Comment: @MarinBonacci : A Kind request, when u tried a proper solution for your questions, pls post it as your own answer below. so that It will be useful for others too. Thanks